# Virtual Machine Port Forwarding Security

Tags: networking, security, virtual-machine, port-forwarding

I would like to be able to have a Virtual Machine connected to my network hosting a game server / Apache server. The only concern I have is the security of opening up ports to the internet. I want it so if the Virtual Machine was compromised, the attacker couldn't infect or access anything beyond the Virtual Machine and get into my main network.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to port forward you would have to put the Virtual Machine on Bridge network so that on your router you can forward a particular port to this Virtual Machine

Example:
So let's call this VM as 192.168.1.155 and you forwarded a port let's 50000

Now following is just assumption

1. your Virtual machine is compromised
2. this virtual machine is on the same LAN as your other computer.
3. I mean if a hacker or virus can compromise a Virtual machines what's stopping him from trying to brute force into your other machines on the LAN

**Suggestion**

1. Depending upon your Router model you might be able to create a DMZ
2. Put this Virtual Machine in that DMZ so it doesn't have access to any of the other routers

[What Is a DMZ and How Does It Work?](http://www.spamlaws.com/how-dmz-works.html)

> A DMZ is a secure server that adds an additional layer of security to
>   a network and acts as a buffer between a local area network (LAN) and
>   a less secure network which is the Internet. A DMZ server is known as
>   a Data Management Zone and provides secure services to local area
>   network users for email, Web applications, ftp, and other applications
>   that require access to the Internet. DMZ in networking gets its name
>   from the demilitarized zones, which is land that the military would
>   use as a barrier against the enemy.

[What is the real function and use of a DMZ on a network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-is-the-real-function-and-use-of-a-dmz-on-a-network)

Comment: That's the perfect term, a demilitarized zone! Now I just need to go about setting one up.

Comment: The problem here is, that as a VM, unless the VM is on a differant IP network, the routers DMZ feature would only forward all unsolicited traffic to the VM. it would NOT prevent the VM from attacking other systems on the LAN. The only way to prevent that is either via firewalling such that no system trusts the VM. Depending on how the internal network is defined, it may be difficult to send traffic to the VM on a different IP network as it must take the same physical path as the LAN host.

Comment: @FrankThomas Can you please write a full answer? How can I make it so that other systems on network do not trust the VM? And my host machine has file sharing enables so on the guest I can easily access the files I need from the host.

Comment: "I mean if a hacker or virus can compromise a Virtual machines what's stopping him from trying to brute force into your other machines on the LAN" - For many the utility of a VM is to run untrusted programs, so to answer your question: the  virtual machine is stopping the hacker, and the answer should detail how port forwarding affects that containment.